# How to group items (food groups) in Swift?

Tags: swift

So I am developing an application such as a food logger that will allow users to list foods that irritate their stomachs and group these foods together as part of a larger group. An example would be a user listing milk and yogurt as items that cause stomach irritation and the app groups these items into a Dairy category. How can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: Show what you have already. Show your data structures. Show what you have already. Show what you've tried. Show what you have already.

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific

Comment: First you need to be able to explain to the computer what "Food", "Dairy", and "Categories" are. This involves designing data structures; writing code in Swift is a whole other step.

Answer (score 2):

You're question is incomparably vague, but I'll try to give you an idea.

Make a dictionary that maps from Categories to Arrays of members of those categories.

```
let dict = [
    "Dairy" : [
        "Milk",
        "Cheese",
        "Butter"
    ],
    "Meat" : [
        "Beef",
        "Pork",
        "Chicken"
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var foodsThatHurtStomach = [String]()
```

Then if milk is one of those items,

```
foodsThatHurtStomach.append("milk")
```

If you want to add all of the elements to another array,

```
for food in foodsThatHurtStomach {
    otherArray.append(food)
}
```